# Problems with prompt js typeof

Tags: javascript, prompt, typeof

I have problems with check prompt data. I need to check, if the prompt data will be string, paragraph could show that data is not number. But according to my code, when I enter string data, it shows me odd or even message, but not 'Not number'. What's can be wrong? Thanks a lot!

[image: my code]

Comment: please post code as code, not as an image...

Answer (score 1):

`prompt()` **always returns a string**, use `parseInt(prompt(), 10)` to convert it to a string (10 is the numeric base, eg.: 2 means its a binary number)

It will return either a number or a `NaN` (**N**ot **A** **N**umber) value.

`typeof(NaN) === 'number'`

`NaN === NaN` will result in false, use `Number.isNaN` to check if the value of a variable is NaN

`if (!(a === b))` is the same as `if (a !== b)`

---

Please, next time post your code as text instead of a sharing print screen of it, so we can ctrl+c, ctrl+v  it

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Because your second if condition evaluates as:

```
 !("nonsense" % 2 === 0)
 !(NaN % 2 === 0)
 !(NaN === 0)
 !(false)
 true
```

therefore it will always show Odd" for non numbers. Maybe you should validate your data *before* you use it. Additionally `val` will *always* be of type "string", you might want to parse it properly:

```
 const num = parseInt(prompt("A number?"), 10);
 if(isNaN(num)) {
   //...
 }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Jonas!